# Looking for LAMP equivalent to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, lamp

We have a fairly large system involving multiple applications running on Windows, written in .NET.  These include a number of web applications using ASP.NET.

We have a number of unrelated web applications written in LAMP - Linux/Apache/MySQL/Php.

The greatest advantage we've seen in ASP.NET is the ease with which code can be shared between web applications, win-form applications, windows console applications, and windows services.  We have signficant code in .NET assemblies that are shared across all of these environments.

Apache/Php has some significant advantages over ASP.NET as a web programming environment, but if there is anything in it that is equivalent to .NET when it comes to integrating code that is shared across non-web applications, I'm unaware of it.

So I'm asking.  Are there any technologies that provide the same sort of easy and seamless integration of shared code modules between Apache/Php and non-web applications?

Comment: As LAMP is to Linux/Apache/MySQL/Php; WIN is to Windows/IIS/.NET ;)

Comment: Somehow someone did something that gave me points for this, 11 years later.

I have to say that now, the answer is clear - .NET 5.0

Comment: it is amazing the long tail on some questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only environment with most of what you are asking for is Java.

Take the same code, stick it in a swing app, servlet, applet, heck even throw it in a mobile device, it'll work. JDBC should be a nice abstraction over most databases, so you're clear in that area.

Other than that, requesting something similar over the LAMP stack is something I believe does not exist at the moment.

Comment: I'd been aware of Mono, and it didn't look quite ready for prime time.  Java I'd not considered, and I should have.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but I do know that Mono has a runtime module that can be plugged into Apache, effectively running an ASP.NET application under it. See [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/israelio/archive/2005/09/11/424852.aspx) on the blog on how to do this.

**Edit:** As per ***Robert***'s comment, the link on that blog is broken! Here's the official [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/) to sourceforge.net. Sorry!

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Blog entry has broken link to the required software.

Comment: @Robert: Here's the link...did not know it was broken, Sorry! http://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-aspdotnet/